# ngx-bootstrap: Modal opens up as small instead of large

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am calling a modal from another component and the problem is I can only get it to open as small, not as large

comp1.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg" (click)="openModal()">Upload
```

comp1.ts

```
import {modalComponent} from '../pages/modals/new-modal';

private modalService: BsModalService

constructor(private modalService: BsModalService)

openModal() {
    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(modalComponent);
 }
```

modal.component.ts

```
constructor(private modalService: BsModalService, public bsModalRef: BsModalRef)
```

modal.html

```
<div bsModal #newModal="bs-modal"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you try encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None in you component

Comment: Which component should I add it in? In the modals or the one that is calling the modal?

Comment: modal component

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try like this :

```js
openModal() {
   this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(modalComponent, { class: 'modal-lg' });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to pass data to modal component while opening modal,

```
openModal() {
   const initialState = {
     data:"Test data"
   }
   this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(modalComponent, {initialState, class: 'modal-lg'});
}
```